# Force Visual Studio 2022 to NOT use proxy

Tags: visual-studio, proxy, visual-studio-2022

Is there a way to configure VS2022 to not use the system proxy but connect directly to the internet?

Using VS2022 with Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

Edit the devenv.exe.config file here C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\IDE

and add the defaultProxy element as below in the System.Net block:

```
   <system.net>
        <defaultProxy enabled="false"></defaultProxy>
      <settings>
        <ipv6 enabled="true"/>
      </settings>
</system.net>
```

On a fresh install of VS 2022 Professional, package retrievals via Nuget were causing a Proxy authentication dialog to appear. Adding the above, and restarting VS solved the problem for me